# powershell - how to find and rename a specific field in json file

Tags: json, powershell

I have the following json file

```
{
  "Encryptme": false,
  "Values": {
    "widget_STORAGE": "somevalue",
  },
  "otherdata": {}
}
```

I need to search for the field that has _storage and rename it.  the final json should look like this:

```
{
  "Encryptme": false,
  "Values": {
    "NewWidgetName": "somevalue",
  },
  "otherdata": {}
}
```

So far, I've figured out how to grab the json content, I think:

```
$content = Get-Content 'mytest.json' -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
echo $content

$content.update | % {if(???? -like '*_STORAGE'){???}}
$content | ConvertTo-Json -depth 32| set-content 'mytest.json'
```

But I don't know how to look for any field with the _STORAGE.
Presently try to google regex in powershell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the metadata about properties of a PowerShell object using `$myVar.psobject.Properties` - from there you can filter for those that end with a "_STORAGE" suffix and replace them with new properties with the "_STORAGE" removed...

```
# the original json text
$json = @"
{
  "Encryptme": false,
  "Values": {
    "widget_STORAGE": "somevalue",
  },
  "otherdata": {}
}
"@

# convert to a PSCustomObject
$data = $json | ConvertFrom-Json

# find all child properties of the "Values" object whose name ends with "_STORAGE"
$properties = $data.Values.psobject.properties `
    | where-object { $_.Name.EndsWith("_STORAGE") }

foreach( $property in $properties )
{

    # remove _STORAGE from the end of the property name
    $oldName = $property.Name;
    $newName = $oldName.Substring(0, $oldName.Length - "_STORAGE".Length);

    # remember the current value of the old property
    $value = $property.Value;

    # remove the "*_STORAGE" property
    $data.Values.psobject.Properties.Remove($oldName);

    # add the new property
    $data.Values | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $newName -NotePropertyValue $value;

}

# convert back to json
$json = $data | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99

#{
#  "Encryptme": false,
#  "Values": {
#    "widget": "somevalue",
#  },
#  "otherdata": {}
#}
```

Note that this will change the "natural" order of the properties because the new properties will be appended to the end - for example:

```json
{
  "Encryptme": false,
  "Values": {
    "widget_STORAGE": "somevalue",
    "otherProperty": "otherValue"
  },
  "otherdata": {}
}
```

would become

```json
{
  "Encryptme": false,
  "Values": {
    "otherProperty": "otherValue",
    "widget": "somevalue"
  },
  "otherdata": {}
}
```

with the new `widget` property moved to the end of the `Values` object. If that's a problem then you might need to do some slightly more sophisticated manipulation, but it'll be basically the same idea.

Comment: Good stuff! Note `.EndsWith()` is case sensitive.  Not clear from the question if that's good or bad.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking along similar lines to [mclayton's good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67824387/4749264) except I tried working it out with a `Select-Object` command. Especially considering the return objects from `ConvertFrom-Json` are already types as `[PSCustomObject]`.

```
$Json =
@"
{
    "Encryptme": false,
    "Values": {
      "widget_STORAGE": "somevalue"
    },
    "otherdata": {}
  }
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json

$ExcludedProps = $Json.Values.psobject.Properties | Where-Object{ $_.Name -match "_STORAGE$" }
$IncludeProps  = @( $Json.Values.psobject.Properties | Where-Object{ $_.Name -notin $ExcludedProps.Name} )
$Expression    = @{Name = ($ExcludedProps.Name -replace '_STORAGE$', '') ; Expression = { $_.( $ExcludedProps.Name) }}
$IncludeProps  += $Expression

$Json.Values = 
$Json.Values | 
Select-Object -ExcludeProperty $ExcludedProps.Name -Property $IncludeProps
```

The important thing to recognize from either answer it the utility of using `.PSObject` to get meta data about the properties you can then work with further.

Note: I'm not sure how this would react if there were multiple properties going by the matched name.  For that again we may need to incorporate a loop something like mclayton's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the [`-AsHashTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.1#parameters) Parameter:

```
$Json = '{
  "Encryptme": false,
  "Values": {
    "widget_STORAGE": "somevalue",
  },
  "otherdata": {}
}'

$Object = $Json |ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashTable
ForEach ($Key in @($Object.Values.Get_Keys().Where{$_ -like '*_STORAGE'})) {
    $Object.Values.widget = $Object.Values.$Key
    $Object.Values.Remove($Key)
}
$Object |ConvertTo-Json

{
  "Encryptme": false,
  "otherdata": {},
  "Values": {
    "widget": "somevalue"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few ways you could tackle this and it really depends on how much you know about the source data at all times.  You could walk the tree looking for properties, but if you're already thinking about going the regex route, then you don't want to convert it from JSON first.  Bring the data in as a string, like so you already are:

```
$before = Get-Content C:\temp\json.txt -Raw
```

To find and replace the text, you can use something like this:

```
$after = $before -ireplace '"(.*?)_STORAGE":','"$1":'
```

To break it down, `ireplace` does a case-insensitive replacement of text.  The RegEx string is `"(.*?)_STORAGE":` which says look for a value in quotes that starts with anything (`(.*?)`), and then ends in `_STORAGE`.  The `(.*?)` is a match group and will be stored in the variable `$1` for the purposes of the replacement.

The second parameter for `-ireplace` shows what to replace that found value with.  In this case, we'll replace it with the match group (`$1`) we found in the serach surrounded by quotes and ending in a colon.

Before going down the RegEx road, you have to know that your data is always going to look like this.  If there suddenly a space before the colon in some instances, the regex isn't going to find it.

If you need to then import the object as JSON, you can then `ConvertFrom-Json` the `$after` param, or you could write it back out to the file if that's all you cared to do.

Comment: This approach fails for some valid json snippets like ```"widget_\u0053TORAGE": "somevalue"``` and ```"widget":\r\n"somevalue"```. That might not be an issue with the dataset the OP has, but in general I prefer to work with the nodes directly and let the parser handle all the funky encoding issues. Horses for courses, I guess...